# Dawn, Dusk.. what's a word for middle of the day?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word to best describe the position of the sun when it's directly above and very bright?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A single term for the duration between sunrise and sunset?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237596/a-single-term-for-the-duration-between-sunrise-and-sunset)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean noon? That's the most common word that people use. Others say midday, or afternoon, but I believe afternoon is time after 12:00 pm.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the time when the sun is crossing your local meridian, you are looking for **"noon"**.

> - "The time or point in the sun's path at which the sun is on the local meridian." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/noon) -   the middle of the day, 12 o'clock in the daytime [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noon)

or **"high noon"**

> - "The exact moment of noon."

Comment: The other guy already suggested *noon*. I think there's a case to be made for *mid-day*, which is more inclusive.